# Add floating button in fragment

Tags: android

I need to add a floating button in a tab fragment, below is my code, kindly assist -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_tab2slider"
        android:name="com.s2s.doupnow.Tab2SliderFragment"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_tab2horizontalgrids"
        android:name="com.s2s.doupnow.Tab2HorizontalGridsFragment"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

can i add the floating button code here, i tried but it is coming at bottom but below the second fragment, i need it to be above 2nd floating button.

Comment: Don't use a `LinearLayout` for the root `View`. Use something that allows its children to overlap, like a `RelativeLayout`, `CoordinatorLayout`, etc.

Comment: done bro thnx, it helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code and try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```